# How to populate select ng options using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Am trying to populate the values in the select, using angular ng options.In my array object i should not add the value in the select if it doesn't have the 'id' attribute in the array.

Expectation:

Should populate only the values which has 'id' attribute in array object.

Current Behavior:

Currently it is not filtering properly and the object which doesn't have id attribute is coming as empty in the select options. Added image how it looks currently, it is not skipping the array attribute which doesn't have 'id' attribute in it.

Image:

[image]

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "def"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "name": "ghi"
  }

]
```

HTML:

```
<select id="selectBox" ng-model="vm.selectedVal" ng-change="vm.selectChange()"
ng-options="myobj.id as (myobj.name ? (myobj.name + ' - ' + (myobj.id | formatId)) : (myobj.id | formatId)) for myobj in (vm.myobj | filter:{id:'!!'}) track by myobj.id">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working well, blank is not the array item but the model value is not set so it is adding an item, give a default value like " -- select an item --"

Try this:

```
<select id="selectBox" 
      ng-model="vm.selectedVal"
      ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in list  | filter:emptyOrNull">
      <option value="">Select One</option>
</select>
```

On controller:

```
$scope.emptyOrNull = function(item){
  return !(item.id == null || item.id == undefined)
}
```